# Network line with arrow in US map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to give an arrow sign on a US network map to indicate the direction of the link.I have followed the http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278 link for this and many other but can't able to achieve the same.
I have created a fiddler for this.Kindly have a look on this and please provide some solution to achieve this.
https://jsfiddle.net/AmitSah/bp6p3p92/

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 10;

/*svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}));*/
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.node_id; }).strength(1) )
    //.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(radius + 1).iterations(4))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


// projection definition
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .scale(1280)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

// path generator definition for major cities, including point radius
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(2);

// draws the states
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LogicalInsightscg/Web-Mobile-Dashboard/master/us_new.json", function(error, us_new) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
svg.selectAll(".states")
    .data(topojson.feature(us_new, us_new.objects.states).features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "states " + d.id; })
    .attr("d", path);

// adding state boundaries
    svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us_new, us_new.objects.states))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "state-boundary");


d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LogicalInsightscg/Web-Mobile-Dashboard/master/nodesandlinks.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;


// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:line")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

   var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.referrals); })
       .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");




  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      //.attr("fixed", true)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
           })
/*       .call(d3.drag()
          .on("end", dragended)); */
       .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)); 



   simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);  

   simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);



     node.attr('fx', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('fy', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; });

     link.attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.node_name; });

   function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("distance", 10)
//        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
//        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

    node.attr('cx', function(d) {if (d.group > 0) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; }
                                             else  { return d.x; }})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {if (d.group > 0) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; }
                                             else  { return d.y; }});

  }


/*   function ticked() {
     link.attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

     node.attr('r', width/100)
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; });

  } */
 });
});

function dragstarted(d) {
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Amit Sah

Comment: For creating the markers you should append a `<path>`, not a `<line>`: https://jsfiddle.net/xdmL3b24/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the quick reply.Can you help me in one issue that I am facing i.e I want to drag and drop the nodes to any position but I am not able to achieve this.In the same fiddler, I have given the code which I am trying for this.Kindly please help me.

Comment: If you have **another** problem, please post **another** question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have already posted this issue.sorry to not let you know that link in my previous reply.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063062/how-to-drag-the-nodes-in-us-map-created-using-d3.Kindly see the link and if you have any solution then please let me know.